# Still getting the error "No such module 'SwiftyDropbox'"

Tags: ios, swift3, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I'm having the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40646380/7120487) . His problem is almost identical to mine. In fact, we're following [the same tutorial](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#system-requirements). However, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40653965/7120487) that solved his problem didn't work for me. I opened up my project via .xcodeworkspace and I'm still getting the error "No such module 'SwiftyDropbox'".

Here's the code for the AppDelegate.swift

[image]

The info.plist

[image]

And the Pods

[image]
[image]

The Podfile

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info, like the code of your pod file, and in which file you are trying to import the module

Comment: @PangHoMing I just added stuff. Let me know if more is needed. Thank you!

Comment: So, can you see SwiftyDropbox in the Project Navigator section? (the navigation view on the left hand side)

Comment: You should have a file in there called `Podfile`. Here's a tutorial that should set you on the right path re: Cocoapod installation. I think that's where your problem lives. https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Comment: @Theodore.K and if you dont mind... you just create a github repo for this question, so we can read you code, pull down your project and fix it. (Cocoapods is troublesome sometime :p )

Comment: @Adrian I do have the Podfile. Check the new screenshot in my question.

Comment: @PangHoMing I didn't know that's what GitHub was for/don't use it. I'l definitely do that, and will send you a link. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PangHoMing I don't know if I did it right, but my example project is zipped up and available on GitHub at this address https://github.com/traviskaenel/GaethrExample

Comment: not doing it right. but i can still download it :D

Comment: hey did you add the line " pod 'SwiftyDropbox' " to your Podfile? cant find it

Comment: What @PangHoMing said. Also, it's best to post text, not screen caps with questions. Much easier to read. Easier to read -> faster answers. The steps to install a cocoa pod are listed in the link I posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install CocoaPods on your computer, if you haven't done so already. Here's what I'd do, based on this [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial on Cocoapods](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift).

**==Begin One Time Setup Stuff==**

**Step 1, from Terminal (only if you haven't done so already):**
Check if you've got cocoapods installed:
`pod --version`

If you've got it installed, proceed to Step 3. Otherwise, install CocoaPods as follows:

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

**Step 2, from Terminal:**
`pod setup --verbose`

**==End One Time Setup Stuff==**

**Step 3, from Terminal:**
`cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/YourProject`
then...
`pod init`

**Step 4, from Terminal:**
`open -a Xcode Podfile`

**Step 5, from Xcode:**

Add in a line for your CocoaPod underneath `# Pods for GaethrExample`:

`pod 'SwiftyDropbox'`

**Step 6, from Xcode:**

Close Xcode

**Step 7, from Terminal** in the directory your project is located in. If you're unsure, type `pwd` and it will give you the working directory you're in.

`pod install`

Nuke derived data and re-open your project as a **WORKSPACE!**. Clean caches and rebuild. [You've just installed your first CocoaPod.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IS7Og1zvdy8)

Comment: I just did all of the above and have the same error :/

Comment: Did you clean caches in Xcode, close Xcode, nuke derived data, reopen, and rebuild, yet?

Comment: No, I just did the steps you told me to

Comment: K...then try those steps.